# edit ephemeral interaction by any id

Tags: discord, discord.js

is this possible to do? I been searching around, but it does not seem like there is any post about this topic. Would it be possible to edit interaction by interaction id somehow?

i tried editing it like a normal message, but that does not work, because it is a ephemeral message.

Comment: While you can't edit an ephemeral message from an ID, you can with an interaction token (up to 15 minutes after interaction). If you store the interaction into a variable, you can edit it that way. See [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Discord_Bots/comments/vmu931/editing_ephemeral_messages/) reddit post.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you are not able to edit an ephemeral message, although you could try to follow up on the previous message with a new one which would work.

Answer (score 0):

managed to fix it, looked through discord official api and you need to post a certain request with the token you get when sending an ephemeral message.